# How much does death cost?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In Saints Row: The Third, having your health drop to 0 (i.e. dying) is called getting Smoked. The tool-tip said that I lose a bit of money to pay for my hospital bill when I respawn. How much do I lose exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every death costs you exactly $500.

Comment: You would lose ALL your money.

Comment: Dying with less than $500 in the bank in SR3 means you die in real life.