# What's the penalty for dying?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I get the following message when I die:

[image: screenshot - text below]
"*You died! You were killed! When you lose all your health, the simulation revives you... for a price.*"

How much will death cost you? Is it fixed or does it scale depending on level, money or another factor?

Comment: I [searched for "saints row iv (~penalty OR ~cost) (dying OR death)"](https://www.google.com/search?q=saints+row+iv+%28~penalty+OR+~cost%29+%28dying+OR+death%29) but can't seem to find anything about this.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115959/how-much-does-death-cost (The two games are sufficiently similar that, while this certainly isn't a dupe, it may be worth testing the answer seen there.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The penalty for dying is *500* cache / credits** (just [like in Saints Row The Third](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115959/4797)). This is fixed and does not depend on level, money or other factors. Dying with less than 500 cache will reduce your remaining cache to zero. I found this out by [extracting the game's files](http://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/extracting-an-individual-packfile.3189/) and then viewing the related game configuration file:

[image: Death_cost - 500 - The amount of cash you lose by dying.]